# EJB3.0- Converting MDB stateless bean to stateful bean

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am new to EJB, and I have a question regarding MDB.

How do I convert MDB stateless beans to stateful beans? Options:

1. using bean passivation only.
2. using bean activation only.
3. using both activation and passivation.
4. None of the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 4) None of the above.

There is no "Stateful Message Driven Bean". A Message Driven Bean is always stateless, because it cannot hold a conversational state. It's like a stateless bean with the difference, that it handles JMS messages.

If you are a beginner, the free book [Mastering EJB](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/wiley/masteringEJB3/index.tss) may help you to understand EJB more in detail.